# X-Axis scales not matching with 2 data sets on same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 2 datasets that I'm trying to plot on the same figure. They share a common column that I'm using for the X-axis, however one of my sets of data is collected annually and the other monthly so the number of data points in each set is significantly different.

Pyplot is not plotting the X values for each set where I would expect when I plot both sets on the same graph

When I plot just my annually collected data set I get:
[image: Tax Data]

When I plot just my monthly collected data set I get:
[image: Trip Data]

But when I plot the two sets overlayed (code below) I get:
[image: Both Data]

tframe:

```
   10003   Date
0    257 201401
1    216 201402
2    417 201403
3    568 201404
4    768 201405
5    836 201406
6    798 201407
7    809 201408
8    839 201409
9    796 201410
```

tax_for_zip_data:

```
TAX BRACKET $1 under $25,000    ...       Date
2                       5740    ...     201301
0                       5380    ...     201401
1                       5320    ...     201501
3                       5030    ...     201601
```

So I did as wwii suggested in the comments and converted my Date columns to datetime objects:

tframe:

```
   10003       Date
0    257 2014-01-31
1    216 2014-02-28
2    417 2014-03-31
3    568 2014-04-30
4    768 2014-05-31
5    836 2014-06-30
6    798 2014-07-31
7    809 2014-08-31
8    839 2014-09-30
9    796 2014-10-31
```

tax_for_zip_data:

```
TAX BRACKET $1 under $25,000    ...           Date
2                       5740    ...     2013-01-31
0                       5380    ...     2014-01-31
1                       5320    ...     2015-01-31
3                       5030    ...     2016-01-31
```

But the dates are still plotting offset,
[image: Both Data]

None of my data goes back to 2012- Jan 2013 is the earliest. The tax_for_zip_data are all offset by a year. If I plot just that set alone it plots properly.
[image: Tax Data]

```py
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(sharex = True)

color = "tab:red"
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('Trips', color = color)
tframe.plot(kind = 'line',x = 'Date', y = "10003", ax = ax1, color = color)
ax1.tick_params(axis = 'y', labelcolor = color)


ax2 = ax1.twinx()
color = "tab:blue"
ax2.set_ylabel('Num Returns', color = color)
tax_for_zip_data.plot(kind = 'line', x = 'Date', y = tax_for_zip_data.columns[:-1], ax = ax2)
ax2.tick_params(axis = 'y', labelcolor = color)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without a reproducible code, it is extremely difficult for people to help you.

Comment: Is/are the xaxis column data strings? Can you give a minimal example of the data you are trying to plot? If the x axis data are datetime objects, they should scale correctly. this is probably a duplicate question. Search for `matplotlib xaxis datetime`.

Comment: Added data, and continued question after implementing suggestions.

Comment: Are your data Pandas DataFrames?

Comment: @wwii, yes they are

Comment: I'm wondering if something about my tax data starting earlier than my trip data is messing up twinx()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make the DataFrame index a datetime index plotting is easier.

```
s = '''10003   Date
257   201401
216   201402
417   201403
568   201404
768   201405
836   201406
798   201407
809   201408
839   201409
796   201410
'''
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), delimiter='\s{2,}',engine='python')
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'],format='%Y%m')

s = '''TAX BRACKET     $1 under $25,000           Date
2                       5740         201301
0                       5380         201401
1                       5320         201501
3                       5030         201601
'''
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), delimiter='\s{2,}',engine='python')
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'],format='%Y%m')
```

You don't need to specify an argument for `plot`'s `x` parameter.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(sharex = True)

color = "tab:red"
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('Trips', color = color)
df1.plot(kind = 'line',y="10003", ax = ax1, color = color)
ax1.tick_params(axis = 'y', labelcolor = color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
color = "tab:blue"
ax2.set_ylabel('Num Returns', color = color)
df2.plot(kind = 'line', y='$1 under $25,000', ax = ax2)
ax2.tick_params(axis = 'y', labelcolor = color)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

---

[image]